# stream value does not changed after update event.. (Flutter,bloc)

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm really new to flutter and now I'm studying bloc pattern in flutter.
so I'm trying to implement a function which user click button (blue or green), it should change the theme color blue or green.
but the problem is I set initiaData as purple color and it just shows orange theme even user click the green or blue button.

event.dart

```
abstract class ChangeColorEvent {}

class ChangeToGreen extends ChangeColorEvent {}

class ChangeToBlue extends ChangeColorEvent {}
```

bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:theme_change/bloc/colorTheme/event.dart';

class ColorThemeBloc {
  var _theme =
      ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light, primaryColor: Colors.orange);

  final _colorStateController = StreamController();

  StreamSink get _inTheme => _colorStateController.sink;
  Stream get theme => _colorStateController.stream;

  final _colorEventController = StreamController<ChangeColorEvent>();



  Sink<ChangeColorEvent> get changeColorEventSink => _colorEventController.sink;

  ColorThemeBloc() {
    //wherever there's a new event we want to map it to a new state
    _colorEventController.stream.listen(_mapEventToState);
  }

  void _mapEventToState(ChangeColorEvent event) {
    print(event);
    if (event is ChangeToGreen)
      _theme =
          ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light, primaryColor: Colors.red);
    else
      _theme =
          ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light, primaryColor: Colors.pink);

    _inTheme.add(_theme);
    print(_theme);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _colorEventController.close();
    _colorStateController.close();
  }
}
```

themeChange.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:theme_change/bloc/colorTheme/bloc.dart';
import 'package:theme_change/bloc/colorTheme/event.dart';

class ThemeChange extends StatelessWidget {
  // final bool isDarkThemeEnabled;
  // final ThemeBloc bloc;

  final _bloc = ColorThemeBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Text('GO BACK'),
            ),
            // ListTile(
            //   title: Text("Dark Theme"),
            //   trailing: Switch(
            //       value: isDarkThemeEnabled, onChanged: bloc.changeTheTheme),
            // ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => _bloc.changeColorEventSink.add(ChangeToBlue()),
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text('blue'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => _bloc.changeColorEventSink.add(ChangeToGreen()),
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text('Green'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _bloc = ColorThemeBloc();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        initialData: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.light, primaryColor: Colors.purple),
        stream: _bloc.theme,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return MaterialApp(
            theme: snapshot.data,
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            home: DemoScreen(),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't extended Equatable on Abstract Event, which is used to identify if event Object is same or not. change your event class to following :

```
abstract class ChangeColorEvent extends Equatable{}

class ChangeToGreen extends ChangeColorEvent {
 // Add props, if you want to return data, else 
}

class ChangeToBlue extends ChangeColorEvent {
// Add props, if you want to return data, else 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it is bit hard to understand how.. becasue if I want to pass the props I should do it in abstract class changeColorEvent isn't it? like abstract class ChangeColorEvent extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

Comment: Bloc converts Events into states, so essentially you need to map your logic according to events. See this example, You will get more idea of how to set states and events. https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertimertutorial